# Why does this code crash when run?

Tags: c, string, format, operations

New to C and going to be learning it so I can develop strong fundamentals so I decided to sign up here. Thanks for the help in advanced. What's wrong with my code — it crashes on the final `printf()` line?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // car loan calculator
    int carPrice, carDownPayment, loanTerm;
    float loanInterestRate, salesTax;

    printf("What is the price of the car? ");
    scanf("%d", &carPrice);

    printf("How much down payment do you have? ");
    scanf("%d", &carDownPayment);

    printf("What is your loan's interest rate? ");
    scanf("%f", &loanInterestRate);

    printf("What is your sales tax? ");
    scanf("%f", &salesTax);

    printf("What is your loan term? ");
    scanf("%d", loanTerm);

    printf("The price of the car is %d. Your down payment is %d. Your loan interest rate is %1f. Sales tax is %2f. Your loan term is %d.", carPrice, carDownPayment, loanInterestRate, salesTax, loanTerm);

    float monthlyPayment;

    printf("Your monthly should be about %3.2f dollars over a term of %d months."), (carPrice * salesTax * loanInterestRate - carDownPayment / loanTerm), loanTerm;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: It crashes on the line it tries to print the final calculation.

Comment: `printf("Your monthly should be about %3.2f dollars over a term of %d months.", (carPrice * salesTax * loanInterestRate - carDownPayment / loanTerm), loanTerm);`

Comment: Check the parentheses

Comment: Thanks. It was parentheses as well as loanTerm not being &loanTerm.

Answer (score 3):

1. `Scanf` syntax error in line `scanf("%d", loanTerm);`
2. Printf syntax error in

   `printf("Your monthly should be about %3.2f dollars over a term of %d months."), (carPrice * salesTax * loanInterestRate - carDownPayment / loanTerm), loanTerm;`

   Braces mismatch

`

```
#include <stdio.h>

   int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    // car loan calculator
    int carPrice, carDownPayment, loanTerm;
    float loanInterestRate, salesTax;
    float monthlyPayment;

    printf("What is the price of the car? ");
    scanf("%d", &carPrice);

    printf("How much down payment do you have? ");
    scanf("%d", &carDownPayment);

    printf("What is your loan's interest rate? ");
    scanf("%f", &loanInterestRate);

    printf("What is your sales tax? ");
    scanf("%f", &salesTax);

    printf("What is your loan term? ");
    scanf("%d", &loanTerm);
    if(loanterm<=0){
    printf("Enter valid number \n");//can specify the range you want
    return 0;
    }

    printf("The price of the car is %d.\nYour down payment is %d.\nYour loan interest rate is %1f.\nSales tax is %2f.\nYour loan term is %d.\n\n\n", carPrice, carDownPayment, loanInterestRate, salesTax, loanTerm);



    printf("Your monthly should be about %3.2f dollars over a term of %d months.", ((carPrice + (carPrice * (salesTax / 100)) + (carPrice * (loanInterestRate / 100)) - carDownPayment) / loanTerm), loanTerm);

    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: Must have been really sleepy last night. Been trying to learn how to code. Trying to figure out the next steps now which is (roughly) if (integer) for sales tax and loan's interest rate then convert them to % by moving decimal points.

Comment: Also fixed the last print.     printf("Your monthly should be about %3.2f dollars over a term of %d months.", ((carPrice + (carPrice * salesTax) + (carPrice * loanInterestRate) - carDownPayment) / loanTerm), loanTerm);

Comment: @CharlesMullen Congrats you found it yourself.

Comment: Watch out for divide-by-zero.

Comment: A zero check condition for loanterm after reading loanterm using scanf. i.e. `if(loanterm ==0){printf("Enter valid number\n"); return -1;}`

Comment: Thank you. I have not considered this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// car loan calculator
int carPrice, carDownPayment, loanTerm;
float loanInterestRate, salesTax;

printf("What is the price of the car? ");
scanf("%d", &carPrice);

printf("How much down payment do you have? ");
scanf("%d", &carDownPayment);

printf("What is your loan's interest rate? ");
scanf("%f", &loanInterestRate);

printf("What is your sales tax? ");
scanf("%f", &salesTax);

printf("What is your loan term? ");
scanf("%d", &loanTerm);

printf("The price of the car is %d.\nYour down payment is %d.\nYour loan interest rate is %1f.\nSales tax is %2f.\nYour loan term is %d.\n\n\n", carPrice, carDownPayment, loanInterestRate, salesTax, loanTerm);

float monthlyPayment;

printf("Your monthly should be about %3.2f dollars over a term of %d months.", ((carPrice + (carPrice * (salesTax / 100)) + (carPrice * (loanInterestRate / 100)) - carDownPayment) / loanTerm), loanTerm);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should at least document the changes made.  You should also consider accepting the other answer.